# Avoid iOS status bar jitter when switching between pages of UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm building a simple app that uses a **UIPageViewController** with two pages. On one page, I want to show the status bar, but on the other page I do not. To make the transition look nice, I slide the status bar in and out after the user fully arrives on a page of the **UIPageViewController**, depending on which page it is.

This works fine on devices with the sensor housing (notch) like the iPhone XR, but it looks very glitchy on devices with a normal rectangular-shaped screen, like the iPhone 8.

**iPhone XR example** — *Height of navigation bar and content below it stay consistent.*

[image: iPhone XR example GIF]

**iPhone 8 example** — *When status bar starts animating (sliding) in, the content jumps up, but then returns to it's original position as the navigation bar animates down.*

[image: iPhone 8 example GIF]

---

**Best Possible Solution?**

It seems like one of the best solutions would be to somehow force the navigation bar to always be the full height of the navigation bar + status bar height, so the navigation bar and content stay in the same place while the status bar animates down. This would be similar to the behavior on iPhone XR screen. How can I achieve this?

---

**Existing Code**

On my **UIPageViewController**, I keep track of a **currentViewController** attribute, and update the overridden **prefersStatusBarHidden** variable accordingly.

```
private var currentViewController: UIViewController?

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    if let current = currentViewController,
        current == settingsNavigationController {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

To set the **currentViewController** variable and call the necessary **setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()** method, I override the **didFinishAnimating** method of **UIPageViewControllerDelegate**:

```
extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
                            previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
                            transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

        currentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { () -> Void in
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }
}
```

To make it less jarring, I use the **.slide** animation (if I leave this out so there's no animation, it's still jumpy on rectangular screens):

```
override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return .slide
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to **Leon Deriglazov**'s answer, I've been able to avoid the jumpiness of the content by subclassing the `UINavigationController`. I added the following code to trigger an animation (with the same duration as the status bar animation) that moves the content up while the status bar slides down, making the content appear to stay in the same place:

```
class SettingsNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = 0
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = 20
    }
}
```

*Note: this does not contain the additional logic necessary to detect what type of device it is.*

Here's what it looks like:

[image: fixed jitter]

While I'd ideally like to avoid having the navigation bar animated down with the status bar, like on the iPhone XR screen, this is a much smoother experience. If anyone has any ideas about how to keep the navigation bar fixed in the same location I'd still appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider employing `additionalSafeAreaInsets` in your Settings controller to make it always account for the height of the status bar. Then you might have to switch it out when you present the status bar (not 100% sure about that).

Comment: Thanks! Adding some animation to that attribute solved the jumpiness. While I'd ideally like to avoid having the navigation bar slide down with the status bar, like on the iPhone XR, your solution provides a much smoother experience by avoiding the abrupt content jump I was seeing before.